# в чем заключается типизация в тайпскрипте?

Tags: typescript

Всем привет. Изучаю тайпскрипт, и в первую очередь меня интересуют интерфейсы. Для проверки того, что как они работают, я написал следующее:

```
interface I1 {
    stringProp: string;
    numProp: number;
}

printI1(i1: I1): void {
    console.log(i1);
    console.log(i1.numProp * 2);
}
```

От поведения этого интерфейсного типа я ожидаю следующего:
В stringProp может попасть только строка, а в в numprop - только число. Интерфейс позволит мне абстрагироваться от полей того типа, который я привожу к нему.

Ну хорошо, возьмем такой класс.

```
class T1 {
    public propNotExistedInInterface: boolean = true;
    public stringProp: any;
    public numProp: any;
}
```

И попробуем привести его к I1  следующим образом.

```
let a: T1 = new T1();
a.stringProp = 13;
a.numProp = "asd";

this.printI1(a);
```

И результат:

```
Object { propNotExistedInInterface: true, stringProp: 13, numProp: "asd" }

NaN
```

Ни одного из моих ожиданий не оправдалось. Ни одного предупреждения транслятора. Так в чем заключается хвалёная типизация? пробовал менять NoImplicitAny - один и тот же результат.

Следующий пример:

Берем интерфейс:

```
interface INumberWithFuncProcessor {
    num: number;
    func(number): string;
}
```

Мы будем использовать его в качестве параметра метода (при этом допускаем ошибку):

```
useProcessor(param: INumberWithFuncProcessor): string {
    return param.func(param);  // ошибка, подразумевали param.num
}
```

И используем наш метод:

```
let something = this.useProcessor(
        {
            num: 12,
            func: (x) => { return x.toString() }
        });
```

При попытке вывести something на экран мы увидим [object Object]. Транслятор молчит. По всей видимости в наш параметр интерфейсного типа попадает что-то вроде.

```
{ num: number; func(object): string; }
```

Вопрос, как видите, риторический: есть ли статическая типизация в ts, или это просто рекламный ход.

Comment: напишите об этом на баг трекере `typescript`, это наверное баг или результат не строгого режима компилятора. Сейчас возможности проверить нет, а офф playground тоже говорит что это нормально. Но возможно это результат того что строгий режим по умолчанию отключен.

Comment: какая версия typescript? Кроме того, не стоит забывать, что проверка типов работает, только на этапе компиляции, и тип `any` можно присвоить любому типу

Comment: 2.0. На счет этапа компиляции в js я с вами абсолютно согласен. Но если я могу так вот просто скормить в интерфейс метод с другой сигнатурой (смотрите второй пример, там нет any), то резонно предположить, что язык позволяет мне допустить куда менее очевидные ошибки.

Comment: Минуту, допишу ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Типизация, очевидно, есть. Просто в данном случае происходят некорректные проверки.

Если разобрать первый пример:

Есть интерфейс, в котором указаны конкретные поля, и указанным полям проставлен конкретный тип.

Что происходит дальше, объявляется класс, у которого *присутствуют* эти поля, но им задан тип `any`. Что такое `any` - это заглушка, которая показывает, что тип может быть любой. В следствие этого переменную типа `any` можно присвоить переменной любого типа.

Что получилось в итоге, компилятор не проверяет реальный тип полей, так как типизация работает только во время компиляции, и чтобы определить какое именно из значений в итоге будет у поля, и, соответственно, какой тип, компилятору нужно *выполнить* всю программу. В общем случае это неразрешимая задача, и определение типа `any` отдается на откуп программисту.

В то же время, если убрать одно из полей в классе `T1`, например *stringProp*, компилятор может проверить, что у объекта передаваемого класса, отсутствуют обязательное поле и кинет ошибку. А также, если вместо `any` использовать конкретные типы, например *public stringProp: number;* компилятор опять подскажет, что типы не совпадают.

**[Примеры для проверки](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20I1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20stringProp%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20numProp%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20printI1(i1%3A%20I1)%3A%20void%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i1)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(i1.numProp%20*%202)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20T1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20propNotExistedInInterface%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20stringProp%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20numProp%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%3A%20T1%20%3D%20new%20T1()%3B%0D%0Aa.stringProp%20%3D%2013%3B%0D%0Aa.numProp%20%3D%20%22asd%22%3B%0D%0AprintI1(a)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20T2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20propNotExistedInInterface%3A%20boolean%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20numProp%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20b%3A%20T2%20%3D%20new%20T2()%3B%0D%0Aa.stringProp%20%3D%2013%3B%0D%0Aa.numProp%20%3D%20%22asd%22%3B%0D%0A%0D%0AprintI1(b)%3B)**

Что касается второго примера:

```
interface INumberWithFuncProcessor {
    num: number;
    func(number): string;
}
```

Ошибочно само описание интерфейса, и при выборе опции *noImplicitAny* компилятор подсказывает, что *number* - это параметр, и так как у него не указан напрямую тип, его тип будет `any` и как мы помним - `any` не проверяется в compile-time. Таким образом, вполне нормально передавать в него переменные любого типа.

Если же указать конкретный тип параметра, например:

```
interface INumberWithFuncProcessor {
    num: number;
    func(a:number): string;
}
```

То компилятор вполне резонно покажет ошибку:

> Argument of type 'INumberWithFuncProcessor' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'

[**Пример для проверки**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20INumberWithFuncProcessor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20num%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20func(a%3Anumber)%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Afunction%20useProcessor(param%3A%20INumberWithFuncProcessor)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20param.func(param)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%20param.num%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20something%20%3D%20this.useProcessor(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20num%3A%2012%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20func%3A%20(x)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20return%20x.toString()%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B)